# xcode build to iphone chooses old invalid provisioning profile

Tags: xcode

I've just gone through some pain with iphone and xcode upgrades and keychain failures etc and decided to uninstall xcode completely and re-install. This fixed my keychain issues however the project I am working on appears to be linked to an old invalid provisioning profile.

I've deleted the profile from "Provisioning Profiles" in organiser, and removed it from Provisioning on the Iphone section of Organiser. However when I build an go with the iphone sdk rather than simulator i get the pop up "codesign wants to sign using key "OldKey" in your keychain".

It appears the actual app is associated with the old key and I can't seem to find how to point it to the new valid one.

Crazy thing is at some point I managed to get it to work and install but the application crashed and won't open. I've not managed to get it to install again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. To fix:

1) In organizer, delete the profile from the phone.

2) Also in organizer, delete the profile from the Provisioning Profile list.

**3) Finally, search your computer for provisioning profiles and delete the old ones directly.**

After that, drag in the new profile and it will work.

Comment: i've looked for the old provisioning profile on my disk but can't find anything except the new one? I've tried re-running it and allowing it to choose the old profile and it seems to work. go figure, it didn't yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This caused me all manner of problems! Open the app.xcodeproj package and drag & drop the project.pbxproj file into text-edit. Do a search for "PROVISIONING_PROFILE" and delete the profile ID. restart xcode and build, hopefully it should pick up the new provisioning profile and forget about the old one that was causing you issues.

Note: Be sure to do a backup of the project.pbxproj file before editing it.

Answer (score 0):

[xCode 4 -reinstalls keychain certs that I delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264481/xcode-4-reinstalls-keychain-certs-that-i-delete/5708077#5708077)