# Xcode 4 -reinstalls keychain certs that I delete

Tags: xcode, xcode4, code-signing

I am getting this error:

> CodeSign error: Certificate identity
>   'iPhone Developer: XXX' appears more
>   than once in the keychain. The
>   codesign tool requires there only be
>   one.

At first I though, no worries, I will just go into keychain and delete the duplicate (older) one, which I did. I went back, closed Xcode, reopened Xcode and project, same error.  wtf I though to myself.  Back into keychain and the cert is there again.  I delete both certs, repeat, and notice as the project loads, the two certs I deleted pop back into the keychain.

After much searching, I ensured I did not have the cert in the system keychain, which I did not.  Also did a clean and rebuild.  When I had duplicates with Xcode 3 I could just clean up the keychain duplicate and I was good.  But with Xcode 4 it literally just reinstalls them somehow when I open the project.  I even deleted all .cer files on my system that it might possibly be pulling them from.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have same problem. It happens because Keychain doesn't remove certificate properly and you have situation when 2 certs appears (but one is invalid). Just remove invalid in Keychain app and this will works fine. But it is temp solution. :(

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The solution was to go into organizer - under library - provisioning profiles, delete all of them and then reinstall any profiles I still needed.

Comment: Yup! I can confirm this works. Even though I kept deleting the one in the keychain it kept reappearing. Once I removed the old Provisioning Profiles from the Organizer all was as normal. Thanks! :)

Comment: Works for me too! Thanks! I think what XCode4 is trying to do is  insert dev certs into your keychain for prov profiles that are missing them even if the dev certs are expired.

Comment: Also remember to regenerate your provisioning profile if you renewed your dev cert. I didn't and when I re-added an old prov profile, the associated expired dev cert was reinserted into the keychain, D'oh!

Comment: Be careful, I somehow deleted my login keychain trying to delete profiles. Not sure how this happened as I am pretty sure the keychain list area had focus when I hit delete. Backup before deleting and be careful.

Comment: This is helped but like others have said, you actually need to go the keychain and delete the expired developer certificate, not only provisioning profile.

Comment: I deleted all my provisioning profiles and they automatically refresh, including some of the expired ones. I've also tried deleting all of my certs from Keychain and pressing refresh. I still have the bug. I'll have to try recreating everything from scratch when I have time.

Comment: Make sure you *also* delete the old profiles from keychain. My Xcode was still using the old cert even though i had cleaned up organizer. After i removed them from keychain all was well

Comment: That fixed everything. I kept having angst about the bunch of misfits lying around there doing nothing all day, wondering if I'd have sign hell if I touched them. Thank yooooou! ><

Comment: If you build a thing with xcodebuild command, quitting Xcode.app (in my case Xcode 4.4.1) seems to prevent auto-installation of certificates.

Answer (score 33):

I had this same problem and the solutions above did not solve my problem (well nearly).

I had the same duplicate developer ID/certificate that everyone is complaining about, and I tried deleting all my profiles, revoking/reissuing my cert, making sure there were none in the system keychain, restarting, etc etc.

In the end it turned out there **was** a certificate in the system keychain, one that had **expired** and so was hidden by default in the list.

**Make sure you can see expired certificates in KeyChain**

To do this:

1. Open *Keychain Access*
2. Click *View* menu
3. Click *Show Expired Certificates*
4. **then** look for, and delete expired developer certs

Comment: Awesome, youre a genius. I had done everything listed every where. You helped me solved months old problem. God bless you!

Comment: It turned out that I had an expired cert under the system keychain.  This helped me find it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Xcode 4 has a new feature "Automatic Device Provisioning". It's located in the organizer  under library/provisioning profiles. If you have this enabled it will automatically download your provisioning profiles from the apple developer provisioning server and thus you get the error of having duplicates. The easiest way to fix it is to delete all provisioning profiles and press refresh for the "Automatic Device Provisioning". This will load your provisioning profiles from the server and will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have deleted my profiles and used the automatic device provisioning to retrieve them back and the problem was gone.

Comment: This is the up-to-date solution, worked for me (after trying the other solutions, they seem to be outdated)

Answer (score 7):

if you want to mess with keychain access to remove the expired certificate, you may try this:

- create a new keychain, name it "expired" and move *ONLY* the expired certificate to it.
- delete the newly created "expired" keychain which contains *ONLY* the expired certificate, when asked select "Delete references & files".

the expired certificate disappears together with the keychain. worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6):

1. Remove all Provisioning Profiles from XCode Organizer;
2. Remove old Developer Certificates from Keychain Access;
3. Generate Provisioning Profiles with the correct Developer Certificate only;
4. Download and install the new Provisioning Profiles;

-- EDIT --

Merge @Codezy's answer and @iphone007's comment.

Comment: Your answer did not fix my the problem, actually I have removed developer certificates and provisioning profiles several times, but old developer certificate always get reinstalled. But @iphone007's comment is helpful, I just merge them ....

Answer (score 2):

Deleting provisioning profiles in Organizer's library, additionally, you should delete iPhone developer certificate in Keychain Access. (The certificate's name is probably like "iPhone Developer: XXXXX ..." and indicated by red X sign, as expired)

Comment: Just removing and reinstalling provisioning profiles in the Organizer didn't help, but your suggestion of removing the expired profile from the keychain fixed it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I spent for this a half-day and finally found the solution

1. Open KeyChain Access.app
2. Select "System" in "Keychains" menu on the left part of Keychain application screen
3. Select "Certificates" in "Category" down menu
4. Remove all old certifications.

Then close Keychain.app and go to Xcode -> Organizer

1. Remove all Provisioning Profiles in Library menu
2. Remove all Provisioning Profiles in Devices menu
3. Push "Refresh" button in Library menu -> Provisioning Profile
4. Add needful profiles to your device

Build again your app:)

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, here's the strategy to get around this problem in our automated build script:

1. Before building, move the **~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles** directory aside
2. Check to see if the **iPhone Configuration Utility** is running and close it (certs always reappear if this app is open. In XCode 4.1 you need to close the organizer too.)
3. Run you build
4. Move the **Provisioning Profiles** directory back
5. Profit?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried everything suggested here but nothing worked for me except reinstaling XCode 4.3 magically solved the case.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a really easy way to fix this in 4.6.1. You can do it without restarting anything or deleting any profiles!

With Keychain Access and your Xcode project open:

1. In Xcode, open Organizer - "Devices" and select the "team" with the
   duplicate certificate.
2. Switch to Keychain Access and delete the old duplicate certificate(s). Note: Make sure you turn on "show expired certificates" to not miss any.
3. The certificates will have disappeared from the "team" profile in the Xcode Organizer.
4. Clean project and build.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

the above method not work for my case

finally , i go to keychain

and search the key by entering the name

i finally found the cert which is supposed to be deleted before . then i deleted it and the problem solved

it's really frustrating , and i don't know whether it's the bug ....... really exhausting.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting an answer to a duplicate of this question, some of Xcode's bugs in this area **can only be solved by restarting OS X**.

In the end, I achieved success by deleting everything mentioned in any of the answers to this question, restarting, then manually installing the parts I needed (I did not trust/try the automatic profile/certificate download feature).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, @AndreasPrang, your answer worked when all of the above didn't.  I could see the expired certificate was not anywhere in the keychain, yet when I did a build, Xcode said it was.  Deleting the provisioning profiles (all of them), selecting my name in the Team section and clicking the refresh icon in the lower right of the organizer also did not help. Restarting Xcode didn't help, but shutting down XCode, deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode did.  When I restarted XCode, it rebuilt everything and was happy.

Answer (score 0):

The other reason that xcode keeps installing your certificate is because you did not delete key, only certificate. You need to delete private key (and corresponding public key) as well as certificate in keychain otherwise xcode will reinstall the certificate.

Check here [To remove development and distribution certificates from your keychain](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/CodeSigning/CodeSigning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011201-CH7-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Xcode 4.6.1 and started having this problem again. The last time was a long time back. I deleted the old provisioning profiles and the certificates, but still could not build.

This time it turns out that I had 2 certificates listed for me in the team account of the developer portal. The first was expired, the second was not. Xcode kept grabbing the first one it found while refreshing (or maybe both).

I deleted both certificates from the keychain, then manually downloaded the good one from Apple's portal and manually added it to the keychain.  Now I can build again.

(And I sent a request to the team admin to remove the old certificate.)

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
2. Clean Project

build...